# What is the oriented Fano plane?

Tags: discrete-geometry, co.combinatorics

One way to remember the multiplication table of the octonions is to use the following diagram (which I got from John Baez's [online paper](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/node4.html)): if $(e_i,e_j,e_k)$ is one of the lines listed according to the cyclic order indicated in the diagram, then $e_ie_j=e_k$ and $e_je_i=-e_k$ in $\mathbb O$.

[image: Multiplication table of the octonions as an oriented Fano plane]

If we forget the cyclic orientation of the lines, this is of course a well-known depiction of the Fano plane $P^2(\mathbb F_2)$, which is an example of many different structures: it is a Steiner triple system, a quasigroup, &c.

What kind of object is this *oriented* Fano plane?

**NB1:** Naive googling informs of the concept of *Mendelsohn triple systems* and of *transitive triple systems*, both of which are enrichments of the notion of Steiner triple systems with orderings on the blocks. The oriented Fano plane above is not an example of these concepts, though.

**NB2:** One way to reconstruct the orientation is as follows: it is (up to projective linear automorphisms) the unique way to cyclically orient the lines in the plane in such a way that for each point $x$, the set of three points which follow $x$ in the three lines that go through it is itself a line. In fact, it is the only Steiner triple system which can be oriented with this property.

Comment: Let me add one more object which it isn't.  Viewing the Fano plane as a matroid, this oriented Fano plane is *not* an oriented matroid either.  See [here](http://www.springerlink.com/content/r3w1m2764n25tg84/).

Comment: I hope this does not evolve into a big-list of things it isn't! :)

Answer (score 16):

Here is one answer: It is an oriented line over $\mathbb{F}_7$.

An affine line over $\mathbb{F}_7$ is a set of 7 points with a simply transitive action of $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$, but no distinguished origin.  Here, we don't have a distinguished origin and we also don't remember the precise translation action, but we have a distinguished notion of addition by a square (think of what this would mean for real numbers).  In other words, it is a set with seven elements, equipped with an unordered triple of simply transitive actions of $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$, such that translation by 1 under one of the actions is equivalent to translation by the square classes $2$ and $4$ under the other two actions.

If you take any pair of points $(x,y)$ in the above picture and subtract their indices, the orientation of the arrow between them is $x \to y$ if and only if $y-x$ is a square mod 7.  Furthermore, a triple of points $(x,y,z)$ with directed arrows $x \to y \to z$ is collinear if and only if $\frac{z-y}{y-x} = 2$.  Even though the numerator and denominator are only well-defined up to multiplication by squares, the quotient is a well-defined element of $\mathbb{F}_7^\times$, since each of the three translation actions yield the same answer.  These two data let us reconstruct the diagram from the oriented line structure.

There is a group-theoretic interpretation of this object.  The oriented hypergraph you've given has automorphism group of order 21, generated by the permutations $(1234567)$ (one of the translation actions) and $(235)(476)$ (changes translation action by conjugating).  This can be identified with the quotient $B^+(\mathbb{F}_7)/\mathbb{F}_7^\times$, where $B^+(\mathbb{F}_7)$ is the group of upper triangular matrices with entries in $\mathbb{F}_7$ and invertible square determinant, and $\mathbb{F}_7^\times$ is the subgroup of scalar multiples of the identity.  This group is the stabilizer of infinity under the transitive action of the simple group of order 168 on the projective line $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_7)$.  In this sense, we can view the simple group as the automorphism group of an oriented projective line, since it is the subgroup of $PGL_2(\mathbb{F}_7)$ whose matrices have square determinant.

Unfortunately, I do not know a natural notion of orientation on an $\mathbb{F}_2$-structure.  I tried something involving torsors over $\mathbb{F}_8^\times$ and the Frobenius, but it became a mess.

Comment: Indeed. This construction proceeds from what's called a $\lambda$-*difference set*, a subset $D$ of $\mathbb Z_n$ such that each non-zero element of $\mathbb Z_n$ can be written in exactly $\lambda$ ways as a difference of elements of $D$; in the case of the Fano plane, $n=7$, $D={1,2,4}$ and $\lambda=1$. When $\lambda$ is one, the resulting hypergraph is a projective plane.

Comment: I am confused. The number of $F_7$-affine structures is 6!=720. The number of orientations on each line is $2^7=128$. Clearly, some affine structures are no good, for instance, those that have 3 collinear points follow one another. How do you account for this?

Comment: @Bugs: Admissible sets of line orientations need to admit 3 independent Hamiltonian cycles, taken to each other by a transitive symmetry (or, see NB2 in the question).  Admissible triples of affine structures have to obey the collinearity condition I gave above.  There are 21 of each.

Answer (score 1):

No clue how to answer your question but one way to choose an orientation is to choose a basis of the vector space ${F_2}^3$. By basis I mean a totally ordered basis. For instance, the orientation on the picture corresponds to the basis $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$ where I take the liberty to identify a line with its non-zero element. If you think of the vector space with a basis as "the standard vector space" then you can think of the oriented Fano plane as the standard projective space.